# Is it possible to overwrite "global" variable via Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, mathjax

I am finding a way to make MathJax be able to run on a specific JS runtime with lots of limitations.

MathJax use `global` to access the MathJax object, and this is compiled by Webpack into the following snippet:

```js
function (e, t) {
  var n;
  n = function () {
    return this;
  }();
  try {
    n = n || new Function("return this")()
  } catch (e) {
    "object" == typeof window && (n = window)
  }
  e.exports = n
}
```

The code above will try to assign the global `this` to `e.exports`, and the usage of `global` in MathJax's source code will be replaced with `e.exports`. However, in my JS runtime, `window`/`global` are not available, `function () { return this; }` returns `undefined`, `new Function` is restricted and only returns an empty object instead of a function.

My question is that, is it possible to configure Webpack to replace `global` with some other variable I specify (like `limitedGlobal.someVar`)?

For referrence, I found that the snippet above is defined in [GlobalRuntimeModule.js](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/runtime/GlobalRuntimeModule.js), and I want to change its implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, please have a look at [globalObject](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputglobalobject)

Its default is `global="window"`

You can override it like this in your webpack configurations:

```
output: {
   globalObject: 'this' // or limitedGlobal.someVar in your case
}
```